# Compiling old versions of R (2.11 or older) on Ubuntu 13.10 (or newer)?

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, compiling, r

I am trying to compile an old version of R (2.11.1, specifically).  "Why?", you might ask.  Well, I have a program I am trying to run (that was not written by me, but I am hoping to use in my research) that was written in "old" R, and the program writer has specifically mentioned that R-2.11.1 or older *must* be used.

- I have run `./configure` with no obvious errors (the entire output being far too long to post here, but I have been warned that I cannot make PDF, DVI, or HTML versions of the help pages, which I'm not too concerned about).
- Next, when I pass the `make` command, I am met with the following error (after a long stream of successful commands):

  ```
  Warning in solve.default(rgb):
  unable to load shared library '/home/sbowerma/Programs/R-2.11.1/modules//lapack.so':
  /home/sbowerma/Programs/R-2.11.1/lib/libRlapack.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_compare_string
  Error in solve.default(rgb) : lapack routines cannot be loaded
  Error: unable to load R code in package 'grDevices'
  Execution halted
  ```

However, I have confirmed that the library `lapack.so` is, in fact, in the exact position it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The `R-2.11.1` build process appears to compile its own versions of the BLAS and LAPACK libraries (as `R-2.11.1/lib/libRblas.so` and `R-2.11.1/lib/libRlapack.so`) by default - even if system versions of these libraries are available. For reasons I was not able to determine, these locally-built libs do not seem to properly link the `gfortran` runtime library (at least, not on 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10).

Using `./configure --help` you will see

```
Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-blas             use system BLAS library (if available), or specify
                          it [no]
  --with-lapack           use system LAPACK library (if available), or specify
                          it [no]
```

So the workaround consists of making sure you have the appropriate BLAS/LAPACK (or ATLAS) development packages installed on the system and then adding the `--with-blas` and `--with-lapack` options to your configuration, e.g.

```
./configure --with-blas --with-lapack --prefix=/usr/local
```

The configure report should now indicate something like

```
External libraries:      readline,BLAS(generic),LAPACK(generic)
```

and after that you should be able to complete the `make`.